# libstdc++ static linking in dynamic library

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gcc

To understand question I should tell you more about program that loads dynamic library. It's Half-Life Dedicated server. It uses old libstdc++ which is located next to executable. 
To avoid issues, when using features from new standard library I usually link my project staticaly to libstdc++.

My friend told me that libstdc++ static linking can create problems, if 2 compiled with different compilers libraries are loaded or when I call function from server (which is internally implemented in terms of old libstdc​++).

Is it true? How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The API your shared library exposes must use the same ABI that the host application expects, i.e. the types involved must be of the same layout, size and alignment.

If there are `std::` types exposed in the API or it throws C++ exceptions, then that means the shared library must be compiled using the same standard library headers and macros defined. In this case you can link dynamically to that `libstdc++` that comes with the host application.

If there are no `std::` types exposed in the API and no exceptions are thrown from the shared library, you can link statically to `libstdc++`. However, all external symbols are still going to be exposed from the shared library, so that when it is loaded with a call to `dlopen` without `RTLD_DEEPBIND` flag, it will use the symbols with the same name from the host application if they are available instead of the ones you hoped to link in statically, which may cause that undefined behavior your friend probably refers to. To avoid this, a linker version script is required to make all symbols in your shared library local and only expose the API symbols as global. Something like:

```
MYHALFLIFEPLUGIN_0.0 {
  global: half_life_foo,half_life_bar; # Explicitly list symbols to be exported.
  local: *; # Hide everything else.
};
```

And direct the linker to use this script with `-Wl,--version-script=<filename>` compiler linker option (`LDFLAGS`). In addition to `-static-libstdc++` option, you will need `-static-libgcc` linker option.

Also, have a read through

- https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Cxx11AbiCompatibility
- [ABI Policy and Guidelines](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html)

for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write this answer. You explained everything that was incomprehensible to me. I'll wait a bit and accept your answer.

Comment: @Inline I may have missed something. `ldd` and `nm` are your best friends here: make sure your shared library does not link anything unexpected, see what symbols it actually exports.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is true. The easiest example is if you create an object with `new` in a library and `delete` it in another library that does not use the same STL.

You have 2 solutions:

- Use dynamic linkage for the STL
- Ensure that incompatibilities do not cross the border of a binary (library, exe). The hard way to do this is to make your library expose only a C API (no C++).

Comment: This example is applicable to MSVC run-time, not to Linux and g++.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin It does apply to Linux and g++. It really applies to any C++ platform and compiler. On Linux it is generally simpler as you have a STL installed system wise and all your binaries are compiled against it. But you still cannot mix libstdc++ and libc++ nor you can mix 2 incompatible versions of libc++.

Comment: Being pedantic, STL is a part of C++ standard library, and `new`/`delete` are not from STL.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin `new` and `delete` operators are not STL, they are C++ core language features, but when you call them you do call functions implemented in `libstdc++.so.6`. And that is what matters here.