# Avoiding symbols collisions in a shared library using the C++ standard library

Tags: c++, linux, linker, shared-libraries, symbols

I'm developing a .so shared library in C++ that uses standard library facilities (e.g. `std::map` or `std::vector`).

I had problems in the past though since any application pulling my shared library caused **standard libraries** symbols collisions and debugging quickly became a nightmare.

I'm a novice on linux, how can I avoid this problem and/or mitigate it if I have *no control* on the application which loads my `.so`?

Comment: Put your exported symbols into your namespace.  In-fact put your whole library into a namespace - it's why they were invented.

Comment: @RichardCritten perhaps I didn't explain myself, the problems were related to standard library symbols

Comment: Can you explain that further as the only reason I can think of for getting Standard Library name clashes is version miss-matches which is usually an ABI breaking issue.

Comment: "caused standard libraries symbols collisions". This basically cannot happen unless there are two different versions of the standard library in play. And if *that* happens, you can resign and take up knitting, because there's really nothing else to do about it.

Comment: @n.m. I cannot foresee which stdlib version is the program going to use.. and I can only link against one in my shared library. Is there no way to make sure my .so using ITS stdlib won't symbols-clash against the program's one?

Comment: You build and link dynamically against some version of libstdc++, don't ship libstdc++ with your library, and it works with that version and later versions (unless and until some incompatible ABI change happens, but those are rare). That's how shared libraries are suposed to work. The other way is to release your library as a source and let your users compile it with whatever stdlib they have. If you are already doing this, please describe your clashes in detail.

Answer (score 1):

In short, link your shared library statically against the C++ standard library. Find more details in [libstdc++ static linking in dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44809374/412080).

Comment: This will cause the described problem rather than solve it.

Comment: @n.m. I do not think so. The linked answer elaborates on the subject.

Comment: Ok yes, if you are making a library that doesn't look much like a C++ library (no exceptions, no std types in the interface) then you can build such thing statically. This defeats the whole purpose of C++ in my view, but hey whatever works.